# How to achieve notifications whenever there is change in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to achieve what the title says but without google functions , as i cannot enable billing in any way , i  two apps i want i want to notify the admin app when user has made a new request, is there a way to achieve this (cant listen to firestore change on a service worker unfortunately)

Tried to listen for changes in a service worker

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do (push notifications to a client app) isn't easily possible with billing enabled and Cloud Functions or Event Arc configured to receive changes to Firestore documents.

You could try to build your own backend using the Firebase Admin SDK to listen to document updates and decide what to do with them, but hosting that backend process and running it *continually* and *reliably* is also likely to cost you some money.  Running computing services like this is definitely not a "free" thing.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i have a vps from linude and from your answer i get that it's possible to have my admin api pushed there ? The problem isn't that i need it free it's that firebase isn't available in my country and I'm making this app using a vpn

Comment: This sounds like a question for your service provider.  I don't know anything about that service.